# Asus P6t deluxe motherboard: Changing the battery

Tags: motherboard, bios, battery

Whenever my computer boots I have to set up things in the bios like the time, date, ssd settings... I guess I have to change the battery...

I've never changed a battery on a motherboard in my life.
The mobo in question:

Asus P6t deluxe (v1)

1. I checked the manual but it doesn't say which kind of battery to buy/use and (I feel so stupid) where to find it (I don't see it)
2. Do I have to do anything else than switching batteries, like change jumpers or anything else?
   I am a little worried...

Is there anyone out there who still uses this motherboard who would kindly point me in the right direction how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that specific motherboard, but generally if you leave the battery out for 10 minutes, everything will reset to default. As you're used to resetting everything by now, that shouldn't cause too much additional distress;)

Apparently the battery on this mobo stands vertically & is mounted in the corner by the RAM slots.

From [TechArp](https://archive.techarp.com/showarticle5196.html?artno=591&pgno=4)

[image]

Before you remove the old one, check which way round it goes - they're 'wider' one side than the other to aid orientation, but will often actually physically fit either way round - not a great design, so be sure before you remove the old one.

Image showing both sides - the 'width' aspect…

[image]

It is very probably a CR2032 - most things are - but there are many similar sizes, so just read the number off the back of the old one to be certain, or take it to the store with you & ask them. You can pay anything from 20p if you buy in bulk to £2 if you pay a phone store's premium for them & I've never been able to figure out any difference, so just get the cheapest you can find. You should be able to get them just about anywhere - supermarkets, phone/computer shops, watch shops etc - anywhere that sells batteries.

BTW, the code is the physical size … so 2032 is 20mm wide & 3.2 mm thick

For sake of completeness - link to [Wikipedia - Button Cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Button_cell)

Comment: awesome, thank you very much... will swap the batteries tomorrow... so I guess, I don't have to mess with any jumpers before switching the batteries out (?)

Comment: Nope. Should be good to go :)

Comment: thanks again for helping out!! everything worked fine:)